# My Python/Django form doesn't submit as expected

Tags: python, django

When you click the Изменить (Edit) button, nothing happens, it seems to be written correctly, but it does not work. I expect that when I click the Изменить (Edit) button, I can change the existing task, save it, and in case of accidental clicking exit.

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'todoist'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('add', views.add, name='add'),
    path('delete/<int:today_id>/', views.delete, name='delete'),
    path('update/<int:today_id>/', views.update, name='update'),
    path('edit/<int:today_id>/', views.edit, name='edit'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import Today
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods


def index(request):
    todos = Today.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'today.html', {'todos':todos})

@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def add(request):
    tasks = request.POST["tasks"]
    task = Today(tasks=tasks)
    task.save()
    return redirect('todoist:index')
                    
def delete(request, today_id):
    todo = Today.objects.get(id=today_id)
    todo.delete()
    return redirect('todoist:index')

def update(request, today_id):
    todo = Today.objects.get(id=today_id)
    todo.tasks = request.POST.get('tasks')
    todo.save()
    return redirect('todoist:index')

def edit(request, today_id):
    todo = Today.objects.get(id=today_id)
    todo.edit_mode = True
    todo.save()
    return redirect('todoist:index')
```

today.html:

```
<title>Todoist</title>
<h1>Сегодня</h1>
<h2>Задачи</h2>
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'todoist:add' %}" >{% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name='tasks' pattern=".{2,}" required title='Минимум два символа!!!'>
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Добавить задачу</button>
</form>

<ol>
{% for todo in todos %}
<div>
  {% if todo.edit_mode %}
    <form action="{% url 'todoist:update' today_id=todo.id %}" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="tasks" value="{{ todo.tasks }}">
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Сохранить</button>
    </form>
    <a href="{% url 'todoist:index' %}">Отмена</a>
  {% else %}
    <li><p>{{ todo.tasks }}</p></li>
    <a href="{% url 'todoist:delete' today_id=todo.id %}">Удалить</a>
    <a href="{% url 'todoist:edit' today_id=todo.id %}">Изменить</a>
  {% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

### Edit

I tried to do this, but nothing has changed:

```
<input type="submit" name="tasks" value="{{ todo.tasks }}">
<button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Сохранить</button>
```

That my HTML form that is rendered in the browser:

```
<title>Todoist</title>
<h1>Сегодня</h1>
<h2>Задачи</h2>
<form method="POST" action="/add" ><input type="hidden" name="csr" value="igFpTSKXEVo2dBXw0LdfQT8PZSc78SCdC0rID6Ir3N2cDQOzUeNUdwtMdaTsU84R">
        <input type="text" name='tasks' pattern=".{2,}" required title='Минимум два символа!!!'>
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Добавить задачу</button>
</form>

<ol>

<div>
  
    <li><p>паттат</p></li>
    <a href="/delete/118/">Удалить</a>
    <a href="/edit/118/">Изменить</a>
  
</div>

</ol>
```

Comment: Could you show the rendered form HTML? Perhaps your form is not rendering an action, or the submit device is not correct.

Comment: I am not sure `<button type="submit">` will work in a standard form. Could you try `<input type="submit">` instead?

Comment: Added a link to the screenshot

Comment: <input type="submit" name="tasks" value="{{ todo.tasks }}">
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Сохранить</button>
I tried to do this, but nothing has changed

Comment: I used Edit and added a screenshot of what the site looks like. I also tried what you asked for and it didn't work

Comment: Per my earlier request: **Could you show the rendered form HTML?**. To do this, use "View Source" in your browser, and copy the relevant part of the **rendered** HTML as an update to your question.

Comment: (It is difficult to tell what you are trying to accomplish, but I had meant that the `<input>` submit device would replace the `<button>` submit device. I am not sure why one would have both).

Comment: You may need to clarify what "doesn't work" actually means. Does the form not submit at all? Does it submit but not do its intended action? Be as specific as you can.

Comment: I click the Изменить(Edit) button, but nothing happens, the page is updated and that's it. When you click Удалить(Delete), everything works as it should

Comment: I add view-source, you can check that

Comment: I want to click on the button, after that, so that I have my Task field available to change, and after adding something to this field, save the new value

Comment: I don't know Django, but this "the page is updated and that's it" indicates to me that the form is working - it has an action that it points to via URL routing, and the POST submission is getting to the web server. So your next task is to find out if `def add(request)` is triggered. I would suggest (temporarily) dumping your request contents there (everything that has been POSTed) and then exiting. If this is not triggered at all then you need to find out why.